# Error code 0x80070001 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server

I've been struggling to get Windows Server 2008 running on a virtual machine. I use VMplayer and want to install Windows Server 2008 Database and Enterprise from MSDN AA. The server is running now but I cannot install MS SQL server.

I have installed IIS. When I started to install MS SQL I receive the following error:

```
0x80070001 Incorrect function
```

The error suggests that Windows Installer 4.5 needs to be installed. However when trying to do this I get the following Windows Update error:

```
0x800B0100
```

Any help? Thank you.

**EDIT**

Setup now starts but I get the following error:

[image]

Does this mean that the file is corrupt?

Comment: have you tried stopping windows update service, starting it again and then check for updates ?

Answer (score 3):

Try to reboot the VM and try again.
If it still happens, make sure that the Windows Server is fully patched and reboot again before trying.

Some information that I managed to find on the problem:

[sql_engine_core_inst_loc.msi installer error](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/350062/sql-engine-core-inst-loc-msi-installer-error-rc0-x64?wa=wsignin1.0)

> I don't know what did it work, but I
>   did this two things and I finish the
>   installation:
>
> 1. Disable the Windows Firewall
> 2. Copy the CD to a local folder (eg. C:\Users) and run setup.exe from
>      there.

The explanation why it worked for the above quote is probably here:
[Installing SQL Server 2008 R2](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic958622-391-1.aspx)

> The SQL Server install is not very
>   tolerant of slow drives or slow
>   systems. There are numerous timing
>   tests done during the SQL Server
>   install process and if one of these
>   fails due to nothing more than a slow
>   system then your install fails.
>
> I have seen a number of failures to
>   run a msi file that were due to the
>   install media being on a (slow)
>   network drive. Other failures have
>   been due to a slow virtual server,
>   where either services did not start
>   within the expected time or msi files
>   did not complete their work within the
>   expected time.

In conclusion:

1. Turn off the firewall in the VM and try again.
2. If this doesn't work, the media on which is stored the Sql Server .iso might be too slow, or the VM itself is too slow. You need to improve the speed of the installation process. Maybe giving the VM more memory will help.
3. Download the .iso again, in case it is corrupted.

Comment: I have en_windows_server_2008_datacenter_enterprise_standard_x86_dvd_X14-26710 running and want to install en_sql_server_2008_enterprise_x86_x64_ia64_dvd_x14-89207. I have updated evrything and VM was resterted as well as server

Comment: Could you please post a non-reduced capture of only the error dialog? It's unreadable as it is.

Comment: press right mouse button and then show the image. I belivie it is corrupted http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/e9836654-8715-455c-b11e-b891ce3c9673/

Comment: Found some info, see above.

Comment: I tried all but it is something wrong with the file

Comment: Is switching to R2 an option?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the Windows Update Code have you tired running the System Update Readiness Tool (Checksur.exe).

To do this, follow these steps: 
Download and run the System Update Readiness Tool. This tool runs a one-time scan for inconsistencies that may prevent future servicing operations. For more information about how to download and run the Checksur.exe tool, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base: 
947821  (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821/ ) Description of the System Update Readiness Tool for Windows Vista 
Try to install updates again.
Note After you run the tool, the Checksur.log file is located in the following location: 
%systemroot%\Logs\CBS\
In a default installation of Windows Vista, this file is in the following folder: 
C:\Windows\Logs\CBS

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956702